# Windows 7 unattend.xml static IP-Address ist not set

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-installation

I want to add a **static IP-Address** to my unattended Windows 7 Setup. To achieve this i added the following code to my unattend.xml:

```
      <Interfaces>
          <Interface wcm:action="add">
          <Ipv4Settings>
              <DhcpEnabled>false</DhcpEnabled>
          </Ipv4Settings>
          <Identifier>Local Area Connection</Identifier>
          <UnicastIpAddresses>
               <IpAddress wcm:action="add" wcm:keyValue="1">192.168.166.125/24</IpAddress>
          </UnicastIpAddresses>
          <Routes>
              <Route wcm:action="add">
                 <Identifier>0</Identifier>
                 <Prefix>0.0.0.0/0</Prefix>
                 <NextHopAddress>192.168.166.254</NextHopAddress>
              </Route>
          </Routes>
          </Interface>
      </Interfaces>
   </component>
```

This works partially. DHCP is disabled and the Default-Gateway is set. But the **IP-Address- and subnetmaskfield** is empty. I took a look in the **Panther** directory and there is a setuperr.log where the following Error is described:
`Error CSI 00000001 (F) 80220028 [Error,Facility=FACILITY_STATE_MANAGEMENT,Code=40 (0x0028)] #115# from CComponentDeserializer::ConstructNodeNameFromXml(parent node = @0x33e7620, full name = [@keyValue=", list name = IpAddress)[gle=0x80004005]`

`Error CSI 00000002 (F) 80220028 [Error,Facility=FACILITY_STATE_MANAGEMENT,Code=40 (0x0028)] #649# from CComponentDeserializer::ConstructNodeNameFromXml(parent node = @0x33e83a0, full name = [@keyValue=", list name = IpAddress)[gle=0x80004005]`

But I dont't have a clue how to fix that error. It looks like there is something wrong with the syntax of the **IpAddress** tuple, but where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I fixed the issue. The problemn was a simple **blank space** in the `xml wcm namespace` in the component section

```
<component ... xmlns:wcm="http:// schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Thats why the XMl-Parser could not serialize the XML-File correctly and the erros above happend.
But thats okay, it took me only several hours to see this. :)